# Finding the height of the page in pdf rendered using dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am creating a html page based on the data coming from Database and then converting it to pdf using dompdf. I know about **page-break-after** in dompdf and is able to use it shift the content to next page by using a if condition in php like this

```
if($count_row > 7)
 {
   $html = $html.'
     </table>

    <br/><br/>
    <img width="1640px" height="30px" src="bottombar.png" />

     <div style="page-break-after:always;position:relative;">
    </div>';

  }
```

Everything works fine.
But, now I want to break the page dynamically. Depending on the height of the table after content is entered in each row, if the next row will spill over to next page,then break the page add some headers and add next row.

Since the content coming in each row is dynamic, there is a chance that one page might contain 10 rows, another 15 rows. Hence I don't want to restrict the row limit as I am doing now.

Is there a way I can get height of the page after each row is added in dompdf or from php. I know it can be done in JS but is it possible to do in php.

Also I know the page size, since I am setting it manually.

```
 $paper_size = array(0,0,1300,1300);
 $pdf->set_paper($paper_size);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of headers are you wanting to add? Dompdf supports table headers (`<thead>...</thead>`) if that's what you need. If it's some other type of header, it's a bit more of a challenge, but still possible.

Comment: Hey Brian, I can add the headers but currently I am breaking the page whenever the number of row added to table has reached 7, instead of that I want to check height of page after adding each row and break the page only when new row if added will spill over to next page. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was working with this library and it always was giving me this kind of issues. What I'd recommend to change for phantomJS.

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It
>   has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling,
>   CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

it will allow you to put rendered content and save it as PDF

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html
Usage example: https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g/use-phantomjs-to-create-pdfs-from-html

Comment: Hey Rafal, my content is coming from a MySQL DB, and then rendered into a html which is then converted to a pdf using dompdf. My question is if it is possible from dompdf or php to get page height of the pdf after entering each row in table.

Comment: Using PhantomJS can be solved by creating temporary .html file and providing it to the script as on the example above. I've put this because I know that knowing height may not resolve your issue at all. If you could spent 2h on proof for PhantomJS would you try it ? ;)

Comment: Sure I will have a look at PhantomJS and use it if it solves my problem. Thank you for your insights.